# Tomcat 9 in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, tomcat9

I've always used Eclipse as IDE, and after adding external server Tomcat, it used to create me an instance of the server, where I edited the context.xml by adding the resource for my application, then the data to access the database, how can I do that same for IntelliJ?
At the moment I was forced to add the resource in the context.xml in the folder where I have the tomcat installation.
I tried also with Smart Tomcat plugin for IntelliJ

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a custom Tomcat Context Descriptor under `File | Project Structure | Facets | Web`:

[image]